# Gitorious error on create_admin

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, git

I am following http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/setting_up_gitorious_on_your_own_server to install gitorious with ruby1.9 installed via rvm. When i try to create admin user i get:

```
$ env RAILS_ENV=production ruby script/create_admin 
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- script/../config/environment (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from script/create_admin:2:in `<main>'
```

would appreciate all the help i can get.

Comment: an easy fix is to "cd" to script and run command from there.

Answer (score 0):

Type the following:

```
env RAILS_ENV=production
ruby script/create_admin
script/console production
> user = User.first
> user.login = "christian" # Change to your desired username
> user.activate
> user.accept_terms
> user.save
```

There is an enter after production.

Comment: "env" runs a program in modified environment, usually used to setup variables just for that program instead of globally by using "export". That said, i have tried even your way, doesn't work. Also tried to "export" the RAILS_ENV (and its exported fine) but no use.